# Updating footer image for all excel files

Tags: excel

may I ask if it's possible to update the footer for all of the excel file at once? I have 100+ excel files that are currently using an old certification logo for the footer. It will be extremely tedious to update every single files manually. Is there a way to automate the entire process?

Thank you.

Comment: Asking for code is off-topic. Also, what is your programming language?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.